# Nginx Rewrite with Regex Multiple Token (+)

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I'm having some issues with rewriting when it comes to multiple token numbers.

I'm working on versioning our API so deprecated version calls will go to our latest version. For the sake of simplicity, let's say we are supporting `v4` and `v5`. When some hits our `v1-3`, we need it to go to `v5`. Likewise if someone hits `v6`, it should go to `v5` as well.

Our nginx.conf uses proxy_pass with upstream so I have each version running on a different port

```
upstream v4 {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000
}

upstream v5 {
  server 127.0.0.1:3001
}
```

then we use location blocks to proxy

```
location ^~ /v5 {
  proxy_pass $scheme://v5;
}

location ^~ /v4 {
  proxy_pass $scheme://v4;
}

location ~* "^/v[0-9]+" {
    rewrite ^/v[0-9]+/(.*)$ /$latestVersion/$1;
    proxy_pass $scheme://$latestUpstream;
}
```

The last location block works for `v0-9` but fails to catch when the number is multiple digits like `v11`, even though I'm using the `+`.

Any help on this would be great. Really confused by this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the following block:

```
location ~* "^/v[0-9]+" {
    rewrite ^/v[0-9]+/(.*)$ /$latestVersion/$1;
    proxy_pass $scheme://$latestUpstream;
}
```

The `rewrite` statement performs an implicit `rewrite ... last`, which means that the URI is eventually processed by the `location ^~ /v5` block, rendering the `proxy_pass` statement in this block, *almost* redundant. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for `rewrite` syntax.

The `rewrite` fails to match when the URI is presented as the version string alone *without* a trailing `/`, e.g. `/v11`.

You need to make the `/` following the version string optional. Try:

```
location ^~ /v {
    rewrite ^/v[0-9]+(/.*)$ /$latestVersion$1 last;
}
```

The regular expression `location` block is probably unnecessary, so I have substituted a *shorter* prefix `location` (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for `location` syntax).

I have added a `last` suffix to make the intent of the `rewrite` clear.

---

EDIT: Responding to your comment

Distinguishing between the URIs `/v5` and `/v51` (i.e. without the trailing `/`) is problematic using prefix `location` blocks alone. If the URI **always** had (at minimum) a trailing `/` after the version string, it would be easy to solve by simply adding a trailing `/` to your two existing `location` blocks.

But supposing you need the short URIs like `/v5` and `/v51` to work, you should switch the solution to regular expression `location` blocks.

*Be aware that regular expression `location` blocks are evaluated differently, and that order is important. You may need to move these `location` blocks before other regular expression `location` blocks in order to prevent them from being overridden by other code in your configuration file.*

For example:

```
location ~* ^/v5(/|$) {
    proxy_pass $scheme://v5;
}
location ~* ^/v4(/|$) {
    proxy_pass $scheme://v4;
}
location ~* ^/v[0-9] {
    rewrite ^/v[0-9]+(/.*)$ /$latestVersion$1 last;
}
```

Notice that the modifier is changed to `~*` which introduces a *regular expression* (and also makes it case insensitive - which may or may not be important to you).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that was really helpful. I found an unexpected behavior where `/v40..9` and `/v50...9` goes to the `/v4` and `/v5` locations respectively where I would like them to get caught by the `/v` location. Do you have suggestions for that? I tried to do regex like `(/|$)` but that didn't work.